# Setting timezone in Python

Tags: python, timezone

Is it possible with Python to set the timezone just like this in PHP:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/London");
$Year = date('y');
$Month = date('m');
$Day = date('d');
$Hour = date('H');
$Minute = date('i');
```

I can't really install any other modules etc as I'm using shared web hosting.

Any ideas?

Comment: [to convert time between timezones, you could use `pytz` module](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18646797/4279) e.g., `tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London'); london_time = tz.normalize(aware_dt.astimezone(tz))`. To get the local time as an aware `datetime` object: `current_local_time = datetime.now(tzlocal.get_localzone())`.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

```
>>> import os, time
>>> time.strftime('%X %x %Z')
'12:45:20 08/19/09 CDT'
>>> os.environ['TZ'] = 'Europe/London'
>>> time.tzset()
>>> time.strftime('%X %x %Z')
'18:45:39 08/19/09 BST'
```

To get the specific values you've listed:

```
>>> year = time.strftime('%Y')
>>> month = time.strftime('%m')
>>> day = time.strftime('%d')
>>> hour = time.strftime('%H')
>>> minute = time.strftime('%M')
```

See [here](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strftime) for a complete list of directives. Keep in mind that the strftime() function will always return a string, not an integer or other type.

Comment: "tzset" is a Unix only function.  Arrg!

Answer (score 15):

Be aware that running

```
import os
os.system("tzutil /s \"Central Standard Time\"");
```

will alter Windows system time, NOT just the local python environment time (so is definitley NOT the same as:

```
>>> os.environ['TZ'] = 'Europe/London'
>>> time.tzset()
```

which will only set in the current environment time (in Unix only)

Comment: and even if you run os.system("tzutil /s \"Central Standard Time\"");, it does NOT change the local python environment.

Answer (score 6):

**For windows you can use:**

Running Windows command prompt commands in python.

```
import os
os.system('tzutil /s "Central Standard Time"')
```

In windows command prompt try:

This gives current timezone:

> tzutil /g

This gives a list of timezones:

> tzutil /l

This will set the timezone:

> tzutil /s "Central America Standard Time"

For further reference:
http://woshub.com/how-to-set-timezone-from-command-prompt-in-windows/

Comment: specific to windows, though

Comment: Yes but that completes Richard Simões answer with `tzset` which is only available on Unix systems.

Answer (score 6):

You can use pytz as well..

```
import datetime
import pytz
def utcnow():
    return datetime.datetime.now(tz=pytz.utc)
utcnow()
   datetime.datetime(2020, 8, 15, 14, 45, 19, 182703, tzinfo=<UTC>)
utcnow().isoformat()

'
```

2020-08-15T14:45:21.982600+00:00'

Comment: do not do this. https://blog.ganssle.io/articles/2018/03/pytz-fastest-footgun.html

Answer (score 1):

It's not an answer, but...

To get `datetime` components individually, better use [datetime.timetuple](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timetuple):

```
from datetime import datetime
time = datetime.now()
time.timetuple()
#-> time.struct_time(
#    tm_year=2014, tm_mon=9, tm_mday=7, 
#    tm_hour=2, tm_min=38, tm_sec=5, 
#    tm_wday=6, tm_yday=250, tm_isdst=-1
#)
```

It's now easy to get the parts:

```
ts = time.timetuple()
ts.tm_year
ts.tm_mon
ts.tm_mday
ts.tm_hour
ts.tm_min
ts.tm_sec
```

Comment: Neither `time` nor `datetime` seem to have the function `timetuple()`…

Comment: @Lampe2020 but they have :) Import `datetime` from `datetime`, then do `datetime.now()`, and the resulting `datetime` object will have the method :)

Comment: Ah, so it's not the `datetime.now()` but more like `datetime.datetime.now()` method.