# How can I run python in a given timezone (change timezone from outside)?

Tags: python, timezone

I'm trying to wrap my head around different timezones. How can I run python in a given timezone (overriding the system's timezone)?

Comment: duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301493/setting-timezone-in-python?rq=1

Comment: @HåkenLid that changes the timezone from inside python. This changes it from outside. It's a subtle difference, but a noteworthy one I think. Also, this requires fewer steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `TZ` environment variable:

```
$ python -c 'import time; print(time.tzname)'
('GMT', 'BST')
$ TZ='Europe/Stockholm' python -c 'import time; print(time.tzname)'
('CET', 'CEST')
```

The `time` and `datetime` modules will honor this.

Comment: It assumes a bash-like shell on a platform with `tzdata`. It won't work on Windows.