# how to set timezone in local variable using python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, timezone, boolean

I was trying to read s3 file which is a fee summary report and now i am trying to Check if the report is present and if the report is older than specified time (configurable) and return boolean
my code is shown below,

```
import boto3
import json
import os

BUCKET_NAME = os.getenv('')
KEY = os.getenv('')


def send_notification():
    report = get_report()
    print(bool(report))
    print(report)


def get_report():
    s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
    response = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=BUCKET_NAME, Key=KEY)
    data = response['Body'].read()
    report = json.loads(data)
    return report
```

I need to set a time locally and compare it with the date which is there on the fee summary report and return a boolean value. Kindly looking for someone's help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301493/setting-timezone-in-python

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a column of `dates`. You can convert the time to your desired timezone, e.g. `"America/Los_Angeles"` using the `datetime` and `pytz` module.

```
import datetime as dt
import pytz

dates = ["2017-01-01 14:00:00","2017-01-01 14:00:00", "2017-01-01 14:00:00","2017-01-01 14:30:00"]

for d in dates:
    start = dt.datetime.strptime(d, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
    start = start.replace(tzinfo=pytz.utc)
    local_tz = pytz.timezone("America/Los_Angeles")  # convert to desired timezone
```

To check if a time is greater than any specific time, let's say 9 o'clock, use:

```
utc = pytz.utc
loc_dt = utc.localize(datetime.datetime.today().replace(hour=9, minute=0))

today = utc.localize(datetime.datetime.today())

if loc_dt < today:
    print("True")
```